# Proper way of calculating lighting

Tags: graphics, 3d, lighting

I am implementing lighting in a 3D engine, and have discovered a flaw in the way I calculate lighting. In the combine shader, I get the diffuse color and the lighting calculations.

```
return diffuseColor * (diffuseLight + ambient);
```

As far as I can tell, this is the standard way of doing things.
But, for example, what if the color is 0,1,0, and the light is 1,0,0. (Ignore ambient in this example)
The result would be 0,0,0. But in real life, if I get a pure green bit of paper, and shine a tinted red light onto it, it should turn out yellow. Or at least not black.

How do other games solve this problem?

Comment: I could have sworn that it worked the way I described. I must have been working with computers too long, thinking of colors in additive terms. At least I wasn't the only one to think of it like that, consulted my friend before I asked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A green paper will absorb red light and appear black, not yellow.
Addition means you shine a white paper with red and green light. Then the paper appears yellow.

http://www.physics.wisc.edu/museum/Exhibits-2/Light_Optics/ColorObj/Color_index.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be (for each RGB component)

```
return (diffuseColor * diffuseLight) + ambient;
```

The ambient component is constant and is added after all of the other lighting calculations have been done, and doesn't depend on the light direction or viewing direction.

As Julio says, a *pure* green paper will look black under *pure* red light.

When something looks green, it's because it absorbs all other colours from the spectrum and what's left (i.e. green) is reflected.  If you shine a red light on it there's no green to get reflected.

Comment: Actually ambient light should be traited differently since it does not depend on light direction or eye direction

Comment: @Julio diffuse light doesn't depend on eye direction either - the above formula is right if `diffuseLight` has already been multiplied by the cosine of the angle between the surface normal and the light direction.